# Testing Rails with request specs, instance variables and custom primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm attempting to write a request spec for a Rails app in API-only mode. In the UsersController, a before_action sets the @user using @uid (the primary key), which I'm attempting to assign in the spec.

User.uid is a custom primary key, User.find() works fine in development and production (as does everything else, I'm trying to learn how to test here).  This is the error I receive in test:

```
Failure/Error @user = User.find(@uid)
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
 Couldn't find User without an ID
```

```
//controller
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_user, only: %i[show update]

      def show
        render json: @user
      end
    private
      def set_user
        @user = User.find(@uid)
      end
   end
end
// request spec
require 'rails_helper'
require 'test_helper'

describe 'get user route' do
  let!(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  before :each do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authorize).and_return(true)
    @uid = user.uid
  end
  
  before { get '/api/v1/user' }

  it 'returns status code 200' do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

"authorize" is a before action on the ApplicationController that assigns @uid.
I'm skipping it and trying to assign @uid to the created user's uid. There must be a better way to do this as well...

edit:
I'm using Ruby 2.7.1 and the rspec-rails gem 4.0.1

The @uid is being set with a method in the ApplicationController which is used as a before_action. It's using a library to decode a firebase jwt and return an auth_user object which contains the uid.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  def authorize
    auth_user = FirebaseIdToken::Signature.verify(params[:idToken])
    @uid = auth_user ? auth_user['user_id'] : nil
    render json: {}, status: 401 if @uid.nil?
  end
end
```

I've read some posts that say that you lose the ability to set the instance variables by using a request spec (can't find this in the docs), because these types of specs are supposed to mimic a real scenario as much as possible. The controller instance variable is only available after the request so I'm not sure if it's possible at all to assign a controller's instance variable from a request spec.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have set `@uid` in spec, will not be available in controller. you need to set instance variable as follow be accessible in controller.

```
controller.instance_variable_set(:@uid, user.uid)
```

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'test_helper'

describe 'get user route' do
  let!(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  before :each do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:authorize).and_return(true)
    controller.instance_variable_set(:@uid, user.uid)
  end
  
  before { get '/api/v1/user' }

  it 'returns status code 200' do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

Comment: using this approach I get the following error: ```NameError:
       `uid' is not allowed as an instance variable name```

Comment: with ```controller.instance_variable_set(:@uid, user.uid)``` the error is ```FrozenError:
       can't modify frozen NilClass: nil```

Comment: Which ruby and rspec version you are using? also could you please provide the snippet where you are setting `@uid`?

Comment: I answered your questions by editing the question. I appreciate your help but I'm not sure this is possible

Comment: @Meursault have you tried the steps given in `firebase_id_token` Gem for specs? - https://github.com/fschuindt/firebase_id_token#rails-test

Comment: The example provided is for a controller spec and my intention was to use a request spec as controller specs are now considered soft deprecated . If I used a controller spec I would be able to use the simpler solution you recommended. Unless I can create a test controller to route my request spec through which I'm not sure is possible.